# plotting a line graph, Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot, rdata

hi guys I'm new in R and I'm trying to plot a line graph but it gives me this problem:

```
e_60_f_1900_2030<- c(e_60_f, e_60_f_2010_2030)
years<- seq(1900, 2030, 1)
plot(e_60_f_1900_2030, years)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I don't know how to solve it, how I can plot them even if they have different lengths?

thanks

Comment: your variables have to have the same length if you want to plot them. See `length(years)` to find out how long they are.